# how to delete selected row from DB and JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, swing, jdbc

in this code it just delete row from `JTable` and i want to delete from DB
and when run this it delete from `JTable` and apper error :
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2` but not delete from DB how to solve this ?

```
    private final JPanel panel_09 = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane_09 = new JScrollPane();
    final DefaultTableModel TableModel09 = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Picture", "Item", "Price", "After Discount"}, 0);
    final JTable table_09 = new JTable(TableModel09);
    JButton btnNewButton_09 = new JButton("Delete Item");

    btnNewButton_09.addActionListener ( new ActionListener() {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            int selectedPlanet = table_09.getSelectedRow();
            TableModel09.removeRow((int) selectedPlanet);
            Object desc = table_09.getModel().getValueAt(selectedPlanet, 4);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login", "root", "123");
            String query = "delete from flyer_item where discount=desc";
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, (String) desc);
            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }

    }
}
);
```

Comment: did you try to debug your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You removed your Object from your model before you get the `desc` :

```
int selectedPlanet = table_09.getSelectedRow();//<<--this will equal 2

TableModel09.removeRow((int) selectedPlanet);//<<----remove 2
```

So now

```
Object desc = table_09.getModel().getValueAt(selectedPlanet, 4);
//when you try to `getValueAt(2,4)` you get this error 
//"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2"
```

To avoid this problem, you have tp get your Object before you remove the row :

```
int selectedPlanet = table_09.getSelectedRow();
Object desc = table_09.getModel().getValueAt(selectedPlanet, 4);
TableModel09.removeRow((int) selectedPlanet);
```

---

Then, you will get another error of SQL, because to set Parameters to PreparedStatement you have to use `?` :

```
String query="delete from flyer_item where discount = ?";
//----------------------------------------------------^
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,(String) desc);
```